# Modal Routing With NextJS 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How do I implement modal routing with NextJS 13? It used to be possible with the `as` concept of masking URLs:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

let router = useRouter();

<div>
  {router.query.image && <Modal />}
  <div>
    <Link href="/?image=1" as="/1">
      <a>
        <img src="/1.jpeg" />
      </a>
    </Link>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now `as` is a legacy prop and is not recommended in the app directory.

```
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

const searchParams = useSearchParams();
const image = searchParams.get("image");

<div>
  {image && <Modal />}
  <div>
    <Link 
      href={{
        pathname: "/",
        query: { image: 1 },
      }}
      // ----doesn't work now----
      as="/1">
        <img src="/1.jpeg" />
    </Link>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I go about this issue? TY!

Answer (score 1):

You no longer can use that approach, you must use [Intercepting Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/intercepting-routes) with the help of [Parallel Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/parallel-routes) to create the modal routing. [Here](https://github.com/akhila-ariyachandra/nextjs-app-route-interception) is an example I found while looking to implemente the same behavior in my app.

You basically need to use the `@modal/(.)image/[id]/page.js` in the app directory to intercept the route and use the modal instead. Then when you refresh it will use the route `image/[id]/page.js``

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get this legacy error... try this:

**index.js**

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function Home() {
  let router = useRouter();

  return (
    <div>
      {router.query.image && (
        <div
          onClick={() => {
            router.push("/")
          }}
          style={{
            position: "fixed",
            top: "0px",
            left: "0px",
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            textAlign: "center",
            background: "rgba(0,0,0, 0.6)",
            color: "white",
            fontSize: "50px",
          }}>
          <h1>
            {router.query.image}
          </h1>
        </div>
      )}
      <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "start" }}>
        <Link style={{ border: "1px solid", padding: "30px", marginRight: "20px" }} href="/?image=1" as="/1">
          <h1>1</h1>
        </Link>
        <Link style={{ border: "1px solid", padding: "30px", marginRight: "20px" }} href="/?image=2" as="/2">
          <h1>2</h1>
        </Link>
        <Link style={{ border: "1px solid", padding: "30px", marginRight: "20px" }} href="/?image=3" as="/3">
          <h1>3</h1>
        </Link>
        <Link style={{ border: "1px solid", padding: "30px", marginRight: "20px" }} href="/?image=4" as="/4">
          <h1>4</h1>
        </Link>
        <Link style={{ border: "1px solid", padding: "30px", marginRight: "20px" }} href="/?image=5" as="/5">
          <h1>5</h1>
        </Link>
        <Link style={{ border: "1px solid", padding: "30px", marginRight: "20px" }} href="/?image=6" as="/6">
          <h1>6</h1>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

this file is to handle accessing the url directly in the browser, not through the router (pasting http://localhost:3000/5 for example)

**[image].js**

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router"
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function () {
    const router = useRouter();
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!router.isReady) return;

        router.push(`/?image=${router.query.image}`, `/${router.query.image}`);

    }, [router.isReady]);

    return <></>
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In Next.js 13, you can implement modal routing using the concept of Parallel Routing. Here's how you can do it:

Create a slot for your modal. In the example from the documentation, the slot is named @authModal. This slot will render a  component when you navigate to a matching route, such as /login.

```
export default async function Layout(props: {
  // ...
  authModal: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <>
      {/* ... */}
      {props.authModal}
    </>
  )
}
```

Create a page for your modal. This page will be displayed when you navigate to the corresponding route. In the example, the page is login.

```
import { Modal } from 'components/modal'

export default function Login() {
  return (
    <Modal>
      <h1>Login</h1>
      {/* ... */}
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

To ensure that the contents of the modal don't get rendered when it's not active, you can create a default.js file that returns null.

```
export default function Default() {
  return null
}
```

If a modal was initiated through client navigation, you can dismiss the modal by calling router.back() or by using a Link component.

```
'use client'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
import { Modal } from 'components/modal'

export default async function Login() {
  const router = useRouter()
  return (
    <Modal>
      <span onClick={() => router.back()}>Close modal</span>
      <h1>Login</h1>
      ...
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow, CyberJ.

It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since at least *eight* of of your answers yesterday appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.