# NextJS App Routing - modal that persists on refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've looked into the Modal method described on [this page in the NextJS docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/intercepting-routes) , and at the answers for [Stack Overflow questions like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74835130/modal-routing-with-nextjs-13), but in all of these examples, when the page is refreshed the modal just appears as its own route, without the original content behind it. Is there a way I can set up the folder structure in such a way that:

- There is a page, e.g. `/lorem`, with a list and a button on it
- A user clicks the button
- The URL changes to e.g. `/lorem/new`, and a modal appears above the list
- If the user refreshes the page, the modal remains, but so does the list behind it.

I've have managed to achieve this using `layout.tsx` to render the list, a `page.tsx` that returns `null` to handle the `/lorem` route, and a nested `new/page.tsx` to render the modal. However this brings about other issues relating to access to searchParams etc, and just generally feels very hacky, to have a layout acting as a page and a page returning null. So a more 'proper' way to do this would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution for this is, to create a directory named `[...slug]` for example, containing a `page.js` file (should of course also work with `page.tsx`). So the directory structure would look something like this:
[image: directory structure]

The naming ensures that all paths and subpaths are served by that page.js file. In that file you can get the entered path and decide which content to show or to hide. Here is my example code. If I refresh the website at `/lorem/new`, it still shows the regular content and the modal. You'll probably want to add style according to your preferences.

src/app/[...slug]/page.js:

```
"use client";

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function Page({ params }) {
    const router = useRouter();
    return (
        params.slug[0] === "lorem" && (
            <main>
                <ul>
                    <li>regular list content</li>
                    <li>regular list content</li>
                    <li>regular list content</li>
                    <li>regular list content</li>
                    <li>regular list content</li>
                    <li>regular list content</li>
                    <li>regular list content</li>
                    <li>regular list content</li>
                    <li>regular list content</li>
                    <li>regular list content</li>
                    <li>regular list content</li>
                    <li>regular list content</li>
                    <li>regular list content</li>
                </ul>
                {params.slug.length === 2 && params.slug[1] === "new" ? (
                    <>
                        <button onClick={() => router.push("/lorem")}>close modal</button>
                        <dialog style={{ display: "block" }}>This is only visible in /lorem/new</dialog>
                    </>
                ) : (
                    <button onClick={() => router.push("/lorem/new")}>show modal</button>
                )}
            </main>
        )
    );
}
```